# Tkinter Grid problem for function calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, calculator

I just learned python and was experimenting with tkinter for a calculator program and my formula bar does not show up. I have tried innumerous things including asking ChatGPT, but still no success.

```
import tkinter as tk
import math
from sympy import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x500")
# root.resizable(False, False)


equation = ""
formula_bar = tk.Label(root, text="", width=45, height=2, relief="groove")
formula_bar.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6)


def add_to_equation(value):
    global equation
    equation += value
    formula_bar.config(text=equation)


def evaluate_equation():
    global equation
    try:
        result = eval(equation)
        formula_bar.config(text=result)
    except:
        formula_bar.config(text="Error")
    equation = ""


def clear_equation():
    global equation
    equation = ""
    formula_bar.config(text="")


def add_pi():
    add_to_equation("3.141")


def add_euler():
    add_to_equation("2.718")


def add_phi():
    add_to_equation("1.618")


addition_button = tk.Button(root, text='+', command=lambda: add_to_equation('+'), width=8, height=4)
subtraction_button = tk.Button(root, text='-', command=lambda: add_to_equation('-'), width=8, height=4)
multiplication_button = tk.Button(root, text='*', command=lambda: add_to_equation('*'), width=8, height=4)
division_button = tk.Button(root, text='÷', command=lambda: add_to_equation('/'), width=8, height=4)
modulo_button = tk.Button(root, text='%', command=lambda: add_to_equation('%'), width=8, height=4)
power_button = tk.Button(root, text='power', command=lambda: add_to_equation('**'), width=8, height=4)
logarithm_button = tk.Button(root, text='log', command=lambda: add_to_equation('log('), width=8, height=4)
natural_logarithm_button = tk.Button(root, text='ln', command=lambda: add_to_equation('ln('), width=8, height=4)
factorial_button = tk.Button(root, text='!', command=lambda: add_to_equation('factorial('), width=8, height=4)
sine_button = tk.Button(root, text='sin', command=lambda: add_to_equation('sin('), width=8, height=4)
cosine_button = tk.Button(root, text='cos', command=lambda: add_to_equation('cos('), width=8, height=4)
tangent_button = tk.Button(root, text='tan', command=lambda: add_to_equation('tan('), width=8, height=4)
arcsine_button = tk.Button(root, text='arcsin', command=lambda: add_to_equation('arcsin('), width=8, height=4)
arccosine_button = tk.Button(root, text='arccos', command=lambda: add_to_equation('arccos('), width=8, height=4)
arctangent_button = tk.Button(root, text='arctan', command=lambda: add_to_equation('arctan('), width=8, height=4)
absolute_value_button = tk.Button(root, text='abs', command=lambda: add_to_equation('abs('), width=8, height=4)
differentiation_button = tk.Button(root, text='diff', command=lambda: add_to_equation('diff('), width=8, height=4)
integration_button = tk.Button(root, text='integrate', command=lambda: add_to_equation('integrate('), width=8, height=4)
x_button = tk.Button(root, text='x', command=lambda: add_to_equation('x'), width=8, height=4)
y_button = tk.Button(root, text='y', command=lambda: add_to_equation('y'), width=8, height=4)
zero_button = tk.Button(root, text='0', command=lambda: add_to_equation('0'), width=8, height=4)
one_button = tk.Button(root, text='1', command=lambda: add_to_equation('1'), width=8, height=4)
two_button = tk.Button(root, text='2', command=lambda: add_to_equation('2'), width=8, height=4)
three_button = tk.Button(root, text='3', command=lambda: add_to_equation('3'), width=8, height=4)
four_button = tk.Button(root, text='4', command=lambda: add_to_equation('4'), width=8, height=4)
five_button = tk.Button(root, text='5', command=lambda: add_to_equation('5'), width=8, height=4)
six_button = tk.Button(root, text='6', command=lambda: add_to_equation('6'), width=8, height=4)
seven_button = tk.Button(root, text='7', command=lambda: add_to_equation('7'), width=8, height=4)
eight_button = tk.Button(root, text='8', command=lambda: add_to_equation('8'), width=8, height=4)
nine_button = tk.Button(root, text='9', command=lambda: add_to_equation('9'), width=8, height=4)
point_button = tk.Button(root, text='.', command=lambda: add_to_equation('.'), width=8, height=4)
equal_button = tk.Button(root, text='=', command=evaluate_equation, width=8, height=4)
pi_button = tk.Button(root, text='pi', command=add_pi, width=8, height=4)
euler_button = tk.Button(root, text='e', command=add_euler, width=8, height=4)
phi_button = tk.Button(root, text='Φ', command=add_phi, width=8, height=4)
clear_button = tk.Button(root, text='C', command=clear_equation, width=8, height=4)

addition_button.grid(row=2,column=5)
subtraction_button.grid(row=3,column=5)
multiplication_button.grid(row=4,column=5)
division_button.grid(row=5,column=5)
modulo_button.grid(row=5,column=1)
power_button.grid(row=0,column=5)
logarithm_button.grid(row=0,column=6)
natural_logarithm_button.grid(row=1,column=6)
factorial_button.grid(row=2,column=6)
sine_button.grid(row=0,column=2)
cosine_button.grid(row=0,column=3)
tangent_button.grid(row=0,column=4)
arcsine_button.grid(row=1,column=2)
arccosine_button.grid(row=1,column=3)
arctangent_button.grid(row=1,column=4)
absolute_value_button.grid(row=3,column=6)
differentiation_button.grid(row=4,column=6)
integration_button.grid(row=5,column=6)
x_button.grid(row=0,column=1)
y_button.grid(row=1,column=1)
zero_button.grid(row=5,column=3)
one_button.grid(row=4,column=2)
two_button.grid(row=4,column=3)
three_button.grid(row=4,column=4)
four_button.grid(row=3,column=2)
five_button.grid(row=3,column=3)
six_button.grid(row=3,column=4)
seven_button.grid(row=2,column=2)
eight_button.grid(row=2,column=3)
nine_button.grid(row=2,column=4)
point_button.grid(row=5,column=2)
equal_button.grid(row=5,column=4)
pi_button.grid(row=2,column=1)
euler_button.grid(row=3,column=1)
phi_button.grid(row=4,column=1)
clear_button.grid(row=1,column=5)

root.mainloop()
```

This is all the code I am working with. I want the formula bar to be on the top and all the buttons below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula_bar is on row=0, column=0, columnspan 6; however, you're placing several other items on row 0 in columns 1-6 so you're replacing the formula_bar with those widgets.

Comment: give me a minute

Comment: If you don't mind, I need some more help.

Whenever I use a function in the gui, and press equals, it gives an error. This happens because the bracket does not get closed. I do not know how to fix it

Comment: @KrishnaKLalwani I placed your formula_bar on row 10 & changed the size to 400x600.  I also commented out the sympy line as I don't have that library installed and I didn't see it used anywhere.  I tried a few simple equations and they worked fine for me.  I don't understand what you mean by "because the bracket does not get closed".

Comment: I had used sympy for differentiation and integration. when i use say sin(90), the bracket does not get closed: sin(90

Since the bracket is not closed it gives an error

Comment: @KrishnaKLalwani Looks like you need to add another button for the ')' key.  I don't see any other way to close the equation.

Comment: I really need help for this one. I am a newbie and don't really know how to fix it....

Comment: i added a button and gave it row=7 and column=1 and it closes the equation but it is not working, still gives an error

Comment: @KrishnaKLalwani I think the help you're needing on this project is well beyond the scope of this question.  For example your trig functions will all need the math library to be imported.  You can't just eval(sin(6)).

Comment: Pls check your email

Comment: In the line where you define "sine_button" - change the argument to add_to_equation from ('sin(') to ('math.sin(').  You'll need to make similar changes to the other lines where the math library is required.

Comment: Outside the topic, are you MrPragmaticLee on youtube??

Comment: Oh and adding 'math.sin' works. Thank You so much and so sorry for disturbing you in the morning. It was great talking to you 

Answer (score 0):

You already have items on your first row. You may not add new buttons to where your formulas bar is. Here is the calculator with the formula entry field (but, with the buttons removed)

```py
import tkinter as tk
import math
from sympy import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x500")
# root.resizable(False, False)


equation = ""
formula_bar = tk.Label(root, text="", width=45, height=2, relief="groove")
formula_bar.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6)


def add_to_equation(value):
    global equation
    equation += value
    formula_bar.config(text=equation)


def evaluate_equation():
    global equation
    try:
        result = eval(equation)
        formula_bar.config(text=result)
    except:
        formula_bar.config(text="Error")
    equation = ""


def clear_equation():
    global equation
    equation = ""
    formula_bar.config(text="")


def add_pi():
    add_to_equation("3.141")


def add_euler():
    add_to_equation("2.718")


def add_phi():
    add_to_equation("1.618")


addition_button = tk.Button(root, text='+', command=lambda: add_to_equation('+'), width=8, height=4)
subtraction_button = tk.Button(root, text='-', command=lambda: add_to_equation('-'), width=8, height=4)
multiplication_button = tk.Button(root, text='*', command=lambda: add_to_equation('*'), width=8, height=4)
division_button = tk.Button(root, text='÷', command=lambda: add_to_equation('/'), width=8, height=4)
modulo_button = tk.Button(root, text='%', command=lambda: add_to_equation('%'), width=8, height=4)
power_button = tk.Button(root, text='power', command=lambda: add_to_equation('**'), width=8, height=4)
logarithm_button = tk.Button(root, text='log', command=lambda: add_to_equation('log('), width=8, height=4)
natural_logarithm_button = tk.Button(root, text='ln', command=lambda: add_to_equation('ln('), width=8, height=4)
factorial_button = tk.Button(root, text='!', command=lambda: add_to_equation('factorial('), width=8, height=4)
sine_button = tk.Button(root, text='sin', command=lambda: add_to_equation('sin('), width=8, height=4)
cosine_button = tk.Button(root, text='cos', command=lambda: add_to_equation('cos('), width=8, height=4)
tangent_button = tk.Button(root, text='tan', command=lambda: add_to_equation('tan('), width=8, height=4)
arcsine_button = tk.Button(root, text='arcsin', command=lambda: add_to_equation('arcsin('), width=8, height=4)
arccosine_button = tk.Button(root, text='arccos', command=lambda: add_to_equation('arccos('), width=8, height=4)
arctangent_button = tk.Button(root, text='arctan', command=lambda: add_to_equation('arctan('), width=8, height=4)
absolute_value_button = tk.Button(root, text='abs', command=lambda: add_to_equation('abs('), width=8, height=4)
differentiation_button = tk.Button(root, text='diff', command=lambda: add_to_equation('diff('), width=8, height=4)
integration_button = tk.Button(root, text='integrate', command=lambda: add_to_equation('integrate('), width=8, height=4)
x_button = tk.Button(root, text='x', command=lambda: add_to_equation('x'), width=8, height=4)
y_button = tk.Button(root, text='y', command=lambda: add_to_equation('y'), width=8, height=4)
zero_button = tk.Button(root, text='0', command=lambda: add_to_equation('0'), width=8, height=4)
one_button = tk.Button(root, text='1', command=lambda: add_to_equation('1'), width=8, height=4)
two_button = tk.Button(root, text='2', command=lambda: add_to_equation('2'), width=8, height=4)
three_button = tk.Button(root, text='3', command=lambda: add_to_equation('3'), width=8, height=4)
four_button = tk.Button(root, text='4', command=lambda: add_to_equation('4'), width=8, height=4)
five_button = tk.Button(root, text='5', command=lambda: add_to_equation('5'), width=8, height=4)
six_button = tk.Button(root, text='6', command=lambda: add_to_equation('6'), width=8, height=4)
seven_button = tk.Button(root, text='7', command=lambda: add_to_equation('7'), width=8, height=4)
eight_button = tk.Button(root, text='8', command=lambda: add_to_equation('8'), width=8, height=4)
nine_button = tk.Button(root, text='9', command=lambda: add_to_equation('9'), width=8, height=4)
point_button = tk.Button(root, text='.', command=lambda: add_to_equation('.'), width=8, height=4)
equal_button = tk.Button(root, text='=', command=evaluate_equation, width=8, height=4)
pi_button = tk.Button(root, text='pi', command=add_pi, width=8, height=4)
euler_button = tk.Button(root, text='e', command=add_euler, width=8, height=4)
phi_button = tk.Button(root, text='Φ', command=add_phi, width=8, height=4)
clear_button = tk.Button(root, text='C', command=clear_equation, width=8, height=4)

addition_button.grid(row=2,column=5)
subtraction_button.grid(row=3,column=5)
multiplication_button.grid(row=4,column=5)
division_button.grid(row=5,column=5)
modulo_button.grid(row=5,column=1)

natural_logarithm_button.grid(row=1,column=6)
factorial_button.grid(row=2,column=6)



arcsine_button.grid(row=1,column=2)
arccosine_button.grid(row=1,column=3)
arctangent_button.grid(row=1,column=4)
absolute_value_button.grid(row=3,column=6)
differentiation_button.grid(row=4,column=6)
integration_button.grid(row=5,column=6)

y_button.grid(row=1,column=1)
zero_button.grid(row=5,column=3)
one_button.grid(row=4,column=2)
two_button.grid(row=4,column=3)
three_button.grid(row=4,column=4)
four_button.grid(row=3,column=2)
five_button.grid(row=3,column=3)
six_button.grid(row=3,column=4)
seven_button.grid(row=2,column=2)
eight_button.grid(row=2,column=3)
nine_button.grid(row=2,column=4)
point_button.grid(row=5,column=2)
equal_button.grid(row=5,column=4)
pi_button.grid(row=2,column=1)
euler_button.grid(row=3,column=1)
phi_button.grid(row=4,column=1)
clear_button.grid(row=1,column=5)

root.mainloop()
```